# Pop-up calendar option does not display when I add Date field in webform

Tags: webforms

I am using Date and Calendar module. When I add a component to webform, I selected the Date field > click Add. But I do not see the Pop-up calendar option. However, when I add a content type (structure > Add content > I see the Pop-up calendar option display for the date field).

How I can display the pop-up calendar option when I add Date component to webform?

Answer (score 0):

The Popup Calendar option in Webform is entirely separate from the Date module, so it should always work regardless of whether you have installed Date module (or Date Popup module).

Make sure you've added a date component to your Webform, then under "Display" there is a checkbox for "Enable popup calendar". This option is enabled by default. Now a little calendar icon should appear next to your date component when viewing the node.

Comment: Instead of the default select options for date, month and year, is it possible to use a text field along with pop-up?